# How to Open Index Nav in all Pages

Tags: html, laravel

All my page nav links are working but my Index nav is not working. When i try opening from any of my page links, it throws me this

> 404 Not Found

this is my index code for the nav

```
 <a href  ="index" >Home</a>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: you probably want to look into the concept of relative URLs and absolute URLs and references to the "root", base path etc etc. They will be good to understand if you are going to be using HTML ... good luck and enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

In view:

```
<a href ="{{ route('index') }}">Home</a>
```

In routes:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('index');
})->name('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route URI is (**/**), So your anchor should be :

```
<a href="/" >Home</a>
```

`href="index"` call the `/index`, but you did not define it, so you will get a **404** error.
Alternatively, you can make a name route by `name('index')`, like this :

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('index');
})->name('index');
```

Then you can call from anchor link like this :

```
<a href="{{ route('index') }}">Home</a>
```